# Creating a webpage with a unique URL using react/firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm pretty new to react and building out a little prototype using Firebase as a backend. One of the primary functionalities involves a user writing a post in an editor, which is saved to firebase. **On submit in the editor, I am trying to create a new standalone page for the post** with the firebase uid as the ending part of the new unique URL.

The problem I'm having is figuring out a way to create the new page on submit. I haven't been able to find any documentation for a similar problem like this specific to react or firebase, and was just wondering on a high-level what a good approach to executing this might be? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newly launched Firebase Hosting + Cloud Functions integration can help here. The first bullet point in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions) looks like it describes your use case exactly.

You also mentioned React. There is a handy [sample project](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/isomorphic-react-app) showing how to implement an isomorphic React app with Firebase.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what i was looking for!